# mitmproxy - redirect host

Tags: python, redirect, mitmproxy

I would like to redirect a host by using mitmproxy. At the moment the python script looks like this:

```
import mitmproxy
from mitmproxy.models import HTTPResponse
from netlib.http import Headers

def request(context, flow):
    if flow.request.url == 'http://me.example.com':
    flow.request.host = 'you.example.com'
```

Hoever doesn't work as expected. Can you please help with this issue?

Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code below, which works for me:

```
from mitmproxy import http                                                                                                              

def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:                            
    if flow.request.url == 'http://me.example.com/':                    
        flow.request.host = 'you.example.com'
```

Btw, I made some scripts https://github.com/KevCui/mitm-scripts. mitm-redirect-host.py is the one for redirect host purpose.

Comment: Your repo of examples helped me big time. I found there an example for http.Response.make() that I could not find in the documentation nor else where. Thank you very much mate.